# Invoking one workflow from other in WF

Tags: workflow-foundation

How I can call a workflow from another workflow in WF 4.0? What activity I have to use to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WF4 any workflow can be consumed as an activity if you compile it.  If you need to consume XAML I've added activities to [Microsoft.Activities](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Microsoft.Activities%20Overview&referringTitle=Documentation) that makes this possible.  We have sample code at [Windows Workflow Foundation (WF4) - How To Invoke a Child Workflow as XAML](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WF4-How-To-Invoke-A-Child-86cc6d31)

Comment: Sweet! Those extensions obsolete some of the code I'm already working on. It's good not having to reinvent stuff.